# Docker Push AWS ECR - Permission Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am unable to push to ECR. I'm curious if this is a caching problem with docker? Otherwise, I'm quite at a loss, at this point.

What I'm doing:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 --profile default | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

then

```
docker push xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx:latest
    The push refers to repository [xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx]
    da7bf7d60078: Retrying in 1 second
    0ee50625ffa2: Retrying in 1 second
    bda3199c89c0: Retrying in 1 second
    5f70bf18a086: Retrying in 1 second
    31f710dc178f: Retrying in 1 second
    EOF
```

I previously created the ECR via the CLI:

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name xxx --image-scanning-configuration scanOnPush=true --region us-east-2
```

Permission Policy this user has access to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:PutImageTagMutability",
                "ecr:StartImageScan",
                "ecr:DescribeImageReplicationStatus",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetRepositoryScanningConfiguration",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:TagResource",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:ReplicateImage",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:PutImageScanningConfiguration",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:DeleteLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UntagResource",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:StartLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:xxx:repository/xxx"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetRegistryPolicy",
                "ecr:BatchImportUpstreamImage",
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:DescribeRegistry",
                "ecr:DescribePullThroughCacheRules",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:PutRegistryScanningConfiguration",
                "ecr:CreatePullThroughCacheRule",
                "ecr:DeletePullThroughCacheRule",
                "ecr:GetRegistryScanningConfiguration",
                "ecr:PutReplicationConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CloudTrail error message:

```
"errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/expected-user is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:xxx:repository/xxx with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy",
```

One observance:

- Access Key listed in CloudTrail is different from the Access key in this IAM account. It changes everytime a push is attempted, so I don't know where it comes from but the login itself is successful, so I imagine this is expected?
- When i ran `aws ecr create-repository...` The access key recorded in CloudTrail was the Access Key listed in this IAM account...

Comment: Looks like there's an explicit `deny` in the policy evaluation for that identity. Try looking at all the policies attached to your IAM user identity for policies with a `Deny` effect.

Comment: @sytech - thanks that ended up being it. i guess i was staring at the obvious for too long. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, which states in relevant part:

> User: [...] is not authorized [...] ecr:InitiateLayerUpload [...] with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy

The problem appears to be an identity-based policy that has an explicit `Deny` effect for at least one required action. Since `Deny` effects will take precedence over any `Allow` effect, even though the policies you shared would normally give you the necessary access, you won't be able to perform the action(s) required.

You should look for other policies that are attached to your IAM user to find the policy (or policies) with the `Deny` effect that are prohibiting this action or other required actions.